# How to Minus two dates in php

Tags: php, datetime

i want to minus two dates in php

for example:

```
$date1 = 08/16/2013;
$date2 = 08/23/2013;
$answer = date2 - date1;
```

the $answer should be 7, How will i do that?
thank you so much

Comment: `$datetime1 = new DateTime($date1);
  $datetime2 = new DateTime($date2);
  $days = round(($datetime1->format("U") - $datetime2->format("U")) / 86400);` It will return number integer of days.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Start using [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class for date/time manipulation :

```
$date1 = new DateTime('08/16/2013');
$date2 = new DateTime('08/23/2013');
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
print_r($diff); // or $diff->days
```

Output :

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 7
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 7
)
```

Read more for [DateTime:diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

---

<sub>Please note that various [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) examples are not correct in date/time difference calculation. The simplest example is difference between `2013-03-31 21:00` and `2013-03-30 21:00`. Which for naked eye is exact 1 day difference, but if you do subtract this 2 dates, you will get `82800` seconds which is `0.95833333333333` days. This is because of the time change from winter to summer time. DateTime handles leap years and time-zones properly.</sub>

Comment: how i will get the value? $diff['m']?

Comment: Like I already posted in the answer, if you want days difference just get it like `$diff->days`.

Comment: thank you! its really a big help

Comment: thanks, buddy this is great

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
<?php
$date1 = strtotime('08/16/2013');
$date2 = strtotime('08/23/2013');

echo $hourDiff=round(abs($date2 - $date1) / (60*60*24),0);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get with `strtotime` and minus dates

```
$diff = abs(strtotime('08/16/2013') - strtotime('08/23/2013'));

echo $min = floor($diff / (60*60*24)); // 7
```

Comment: why you divide the diff to (60*60*24)? and where do you get that?

Comment: `60*60*24` is second of days. `diff` result is `604800` about betweeen two date seconds. You have to divide to day. First `60` is min, second `60` hour and last `24` is for the day. So `60*60*24 = 86400` is mean one(1) date.

Comment: How many days difference is from `2013-03-31 21:00` to `2013-03-30 21:00` with this example?

Comment: This is not same format with question. As question format, this is totaly right. No need to force @Glavić

Comment: The problem is, that strtotime() is not ok method for date/time calculation. And the answer should also support time in my humble opinion.

Answer (score -1):

```
$date1 = '08/16/2013';
$date2 = '08/23/2013';
$days = (strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
print $days;
```

Comment: why you divide the diff to (60*60*24)? and where do you get that?

Comment: How many days difference is from `2013-03-31 21:00` to `2013-03-30 21:00` with this example?

Comment: Its one which should be the answer.